# How to set the attributes of the main <html> tag(at the top of the source code) for the Shiny application

Tags: html, shiny

I have a working R Shiny app, but in order to be meet the accessibility requirements (e.g. so that the web page readers for the blind could operate with the landing page) the language attribute (`lang ="en"`) should be set in the main html tag i.e.: `<!doctype html> <html lang="en"> <head>`.....

I have my ui.R code starting with the `dashboardPage()` function, but if I put e.g. `HTML("<html lang='en'>")` into any of its arguments - the resulting app's source code will show this line in the body (created by `dashboardBody()` ), while I need it in the very top `<html>` tag (supposedly created by the shiny package itself when rendering the app's UI).

This is what I'm getting (when viewing the source html code of the working shiny app:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
```

While what I need looks like the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html class="no-js" lang="en"> 
<head>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
tags$html(class = "no-js", lang="en")
```

I don't use shinydashboard, but I think you have to place this code in the `dashboardBody`.

Comment: Yes, it does put the attribute into the html tag, but in the body of the code - which might still pass the "accessibility compliance" test. I'd still be curious to know if it's possible at all to place the attribute into the most-outer (which goes right after the <!DOCTYPE html> and encloses the whole source code) html tag - cause this is where  auto-web-page-readers (for the blind people) set the language property for the whole web page.

Comment: @ryadden I don't see what you mean. I tried and it does put the attributes into the `html` tag at the beginning of the document, the one right after the DOCTYPE. Why do you say "in the body" ?

Comment: Let's take the simplest possible Shiny app:
UI.R:
tags$html( lang="en")

server.R:
function(input, output) {}

If you run it, and click View page source - the source will look like the following:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <script type="application/html-dependencies">json2[2014.02.04];jquery[1.12.4];shiny[1.1.0]</script>
<link href="shared/shiny.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="shared/shiny.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <html lang="en"></html>
</body>
</html>.
the desired line shows up inside the <body> part, while the second line still reads just <html>

Comment: @ryadden This is not a valid UI (I'm surprised it works). Try `ui <- fluidPage(tags$html(lang="en"))`.

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but when I run the following lines:library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$html(lang="en")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
and press CTRL-U in the opened browser window (to see the source code)  - I get:   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>       in the top and </head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <html lang="en"></html>
  </div>
</body>

</html> in the bottom of the source code (so adding fluidPage() only adds a div (of class='container-fluid') around our html tag (with set attribute)

Comment: @ryadden Ah you're right, that's what happens when you do CTRL+U. But open the console (CTRL+Shift+I in Chrome) and inspect the elements, you will see that the tag `<html lang="en">` is at the top. This is Javascript which moves it.

Comment: oh, true. Apparently the source codes look different if you open it in new window (with CTRL-U  or right click and then 'View source code') or if you view it within the console (i.e. inspect the elements). In the latter case it is in the top - so I guess the automatic webpage viewers (for the blind) will be able to use the language attribute. Thanks for your help, Stéphane  .

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `head` tag to include anything within a regular HTML `<head></head>`.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(HTML("<html lang='en'>"))
)
```